# How can I route an External Class Library in my Web API, ASP NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created an WEB API in ASP NET 5 and I can reference an external Class Library vNext.
I am working on Visual Studio 2015 Community.
In that Library I have this controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class NovosController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "i am", "an external library" };
    }
```

To add this library in my Web API´s references I had to browse the DLL's (one for dnxcore50 and one for dnx451).

This is the result:

[dnx451](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W6NX.png)

[dnxcore50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkReg.png)

In my web API I can get the data from that controller but I  **can't** acess it from URL.
But if the library is in the same Solution I can acess it from the URL.

**For example:**

If external library:

localhost:51000/api/novos

returns me nothing

but if the library is in the same solution:

localhost:51000/api/novos

returns me " i am an external library"

I want to acess by URL to the external library but I can't find any solution to my problem, there is anyone that knows how to make this thing work?

Comment: Do you have this is a repo in GitHub we could look at?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special to allow your external class library to be discovered by `IControllerTypeProvider` as long as you comply with the requisites:

- has to be class
- can’t be abstract
- has to be public
- has to be top-level (not nested)
- can’t be generic
- has to either derive from Controller base class or end in Controller suffix (for POCOs) and be located in an assembly *that references MVC assembly*

([Source](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/04/asp-net-mvc-6-discovers-controllers/))

In your particular case, I think you just need to remove the `Route` annotation, since it doesn't looks right.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace External.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class NovosController: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "I am", "an external library" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already removed that route but I still having the same problem, there is no other solution?