# Can't load controller/routes automatically MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have controller defined in other dll, when i refer the dll into my MVC6 webproject, it does not load any of controller/routes automatically, anyone knows a solution?.

Comment: Don't post multiple questions asking the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623383/how-can-i-route-an-external-class-library-in-my-web-api-asp-net-5

Comment: @Tseng the question you linked isn't even accepted nor resolve the problem this user asked.

Comment: @MaximeRouiller-MVP: Look at the user's name who posted the linked question...

Comment: You can try this  (http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/loading-asp-net-mvc-controllers-and-views-from-an-assembly) and also have a look to the source code in (https://github.com/rjperes/DevelopmentWithADot.AspNetMvcAssemblyRoute)